# How to make a dashboard only visible to users of a specific security role?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dashboard, security-roles

I have created a dashboard named *ABC Dashboard* and a security role named *ABC admin*.

What I want is that *ABC Dashboard* is only visible to users who have security role *ABC admin*. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm curious what's the business need for that. It doesn't affect the actual solution, of course, but I've never met such a requirement so I'd like to know where such a thing might be of value.

Comment: I run into this requirement often. It often occurs because you have 20+ dashboards in an Org - some for individual sales people, some for sales managers, some for sales operations, some for executive management, etc. No one wants to look through a huge drop-down list to skip between their 2 or 3 dashboards. I've heard this complaint a number of times.

Answer (score 2):

In short. You can't.

Slightly longer answer.

There are two types of dashboards, system and personal. System can be seen by everyone.

Personal are only seen by the user who has created them - but they can then be shared with other users and teams. Not an ideal solution but does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in CRM 2013 and future versions.